# Usar PDO com o PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Bom dia,
criei uma funcao para obter os ids de todos os processos de uma tabela, como mostra o codigo abaixo

```
    function getProcessos()
{
   $conecta = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=processos','root','root');
    $sql = "SELECT id from processo where opcao='S' limit 10";
    $resultado = $conecta->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute();
    $dados = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       return $dados;
}
```

Agora preciso filtrar na tabela andamentos pelos processos obtidos na funcao acima

```
$processo = getProcessos();
     // var_dump($processo);

     foreach ($processo as $linhas) {
         $linha = $linhas->id;
         $sql = "select * from andamento where idprocesso=$linha limit 10";
         $stmt = $conecta->prepare($sql);
         var_dump($stmt);
         $stmt->execute();
         $dados = $stmt->fetchAll();
         // var_dump($dados);
}
```

quando dou var_dump em $stmt ele retorna 
public 'queryString' => string 'select * from andamento where idprocesso=5873, onde sempre modifica os idprocessos de acordo com a funcao getProcesso();
Porem quando dou var_dump($dados) ele retorna 10 arrays vazios

Comment: Porque não faz isso tudo em método só! em um SQL só!

Comment: idprocesso='$linha' tenta assim

Comment: De um `var_dump($linha);` isto provavelmente vai lhe dizer muita coisa sobre o problema.